# icacls: "Access Denied" trying to change owned files with empty ACL

Tags: windows

I have an odd problem where I can't remove any files with an empty ACL:

```
>icacls "avfilter-7_ms.dll" /grant Administrator:F
avfilter-7_ms.dll: Access is denied.
```

This is what the file looks like:

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u7e6.png)

*No groups or users have access to this object.*

However, when I use the Windows security UI, I am able to add myself as Full Control to the object.  I have thousands to delete; is there a way to do this?  icacls seems to be completely unable to touch these files.

Answer (score 0):

Played around with .NET a bit and this was able to get the ACL entry added so I can delete a single file (needs a ForEach on Get-ChildItem next):

```
$rule = new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule "Administrator", "FullControl", "Allow";
$p = "bad_file.txt"
$acl = [System.IO.File]::GetAccessControl($p);
$acl.SetAccessRule($rule);
[System.IO.File]::SetAccessControl($p, $acl);
```